# Connecting redis cluster using Laravel giving no connection available in the pool

Tags: laravel, redis, predis

I want to connect redis cluster from Laravel but I am getting No `connections available in the pool`. My databaase.php looks like

```
'redis' => [

    'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),


    'clusters' => [
            'default' =>
                [
                  [
           
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
        ]],
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => 'redis', // This tells Redis Client lib to follow redirects (from cluster)

        ]
    ],

]
```

But with this settings, I am getting No connections available in the pool. But if I just connect redis cluster using cli, I can successfully connect. So I believe there is something wrong with my laravel configuration that I am still unable to solve. Any help?

**Solution**
Hi guys, it was a configuration issue. I was using wrong port. The default port is 6379 and I was mistakenly using another port number.

Comment: I think the `options` key should be in `redis` not in `redis.clusters`

Answer (score 0):

Moving the `options` to the parent array should solve your problem.

```php
'redis' => [
    'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),

    'options' => [
        'cluster' => 'redis'
    ]

    'clusters' => [
        'default' => [
            [
                'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
                'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
                'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: moved but didn't worked

Comment: Can you confirm you are using `predis` or `phpredis` in the client, it might not be able to pick it up because of that?

Answer (score 0):

What about adding `scheme` and moving `options` ?

```
'redis' => [
    'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),

    'options' => [
        'cluster' => 'redis'
    ],

    'clusters' => [
        'default' => [
            [
                'scheme' => env('REDIS_SCHEME', 'tcp'),
                'host'   => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
                'port'   => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
                'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: already done but didn't work